Azure/PowerFlow App (Get-PnPFlowRun/Microsoft.ProcessSimple) XrmApplyUserFailed Failed to create a representing user
Current system runs over user + plain password authentication.
2MFA is coming so I want replace it by client/secret solution.
I have did an app in Azure and things like read/write SharePoint is working
My problem: I can't run Get-PnPFlowRun or call urls like:
https://emea.api.flow.microsoft.com/providers/Microsoft.ProcessSimple/environments/Default-********/flows/******/runs?api-version=2016-11-01
In both cases, I get:
{
    "error": {
        "code": "XrmApplyUserFailed",
        "message": "Failed to create a Microsoft Dataverse system row representing user '******' with code 'UserNotInActiveDirectory' and message 'User with objectId:****** does not exist in AD tenantId:*******'."
    }
}

And, yes, the user doesn't exist but I don't think I can create a user with exact the objectId.

did you try the solution described below?

You have to add your app as an application user (also called server-to-server "S2S" user) to your Power Platform environment:

Connect to https://admin.powerplatform.microsoft.com/
On the left side, click on Environments
On the right site, click on Access > S2S apps
Click on New app user
Select your app user and select a security role (System Administrator)
Click on Create




I found the same problem in our environment recently: https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Power-Apps-Governance-and/Error-Failed-to-create-a-Microsoft-Dataverse-system-row/m-p/2800929#M12168
From my experience, I assume that there was a recent change "somewhere within the PowerPlatform" since I am quite sure that the steps mentioned by @jleture were not necessary in the past.
Can anyone of you back my assumption?
